# Comparing rows of pandas dataframe (rows have some overlapping values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 21 columns. I am focusing on a subset of rows that have exactly same column data values except for 6 that are unique to each row. I don't know which column headings these 6 values correspond to a priori.

I tried converting each row to Index objects, and performed set operation on two rows. Ex.

```
row1 = pd.Index(sample_data[0])
row2 = pd.Index(sample_data[1])
row1 - row2
```

which returns an Index object containing values unique to row1. Then I can manually deduce which columns have unique values.

How can I programmatically grab the column headings that these values correspond to in the initial dataframe? Or, is there a way to compare two or multiple dataframe rows and extract the 6 different column values of each row, as well as the corresponding headings? Ideally, it would be nice to generate a new dataframe with the unique columns.

In particular, is there a way to do this using set operations?

Thank you.

Comment: So there's a group of rows which are 15-in-common,6-different and also other rows which don't follow this pattern?  [IOW, do we have to detect this "subset of rows" or is that already done?]

Comment: can u post a couple of sample rows?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a quick solution to return only the columns in which the first two rows differ.

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[range(5), list('abcde'), list('aaaaa'),
...                              list('bbbbb')]), columns=list('ABCD'))

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  0  a  a  b
1  1  b  a  b
2  2  c  a  b
3  3  d  a  b
4  4  e  a  b

In [15]: df[df.columns[df.iloc[0] != df.iloc[1]]]
Out[15]: 
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  3  d
4  4  e
```

And a solution to find all columns with more than one unique value throughout the entire frame.

```
In [33]: df[df.columns[df.apply(lambda s: len(s.unique()) > 1)]]
Out[33]: 
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  3  d
4  4  e
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need the index, you could just compare two rows and use that to filter the columns with a list comprehension.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.ones(10), "col2": np.ones(10), "col3": range(2,12)})
row1 = df.irow(0)
row2 = df.irow(1)
unique_columns = row1 != row2
cols = [colname for colname, unique_column in zip(df.columns, bools) if unique_column]
print cols # ['col3']
```

If you know the standard value for each column, you can convert all the rows to a list of booleans, i.e.:

```
standard_row = np.ones(3)
columns = df.columns
unique_columns = df.apply(lambda x: x != standard_row, axis=1)
unique_columns.apply(lambda x: [col for col, unique_column in zip(columns, x) if unique_column], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @jeff-tratner's answer

1. produce truth table of identical cells between two rows (selected in this case by their index *positions*):

   uq = di2.iloc[0] != di2.iloc[1]
2. get list of columns of identical cells:

   uq[uq==True].index.to_list()

Or get list of columns of non-identical cells:

```
uq[uq!=True].index.to_list()
```