# Comparing row values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a pandas dataframe where two columns contain numerical sequences (start and stop). I want to identify which rows have stop values which overlap with the next rows' start values. Then I need to concatenate them into a single row so that I only have single none-overlapping numerical sequences represented by my start and stop values in each row.

I have loaded my data into a pandas dataframe:

> ```
>   chr     start       stop        geneID
> 0 chr13   32889584    32889814    BRCA2
> 1 chr13   32890536    32890737    BRCA2
> 2 chr13   32893194    32893307    BRCA2
> 3 chr13   32893282    32893400    BRCA2
> 4 chr13   32893363    32893466    BRCA2
> 5 chr13   32899127    32899242    BRCA2
> ```

I want to compare the rows in the dataframe. Check whether the stop value for each row is less than the start value for the following row and then create a row in a new dataframe with the correct start and stop values. Ideally when there are several rows which all overlap this would be concatenated all in one go, however I suspect I will have to iterate over my output until this doesn't happen any more.

My code so far can identify whether there is an overlap (adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409335/comparing-pandas-dataframe-rows-dropping-rows-with-overlapping-dates)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['chr','start','stop','geneID']
bed = pd.read_table('bedfile.txt',sep='\s',names=['chr','start','stop','geneID'],engine='python')

def bed_prepare(inp_bed):
    inp_bed['next_start'] = inp_bed['start'].shift(periods=-1)
    inp_bed['distance_to_next'] = inp_bed['next_start'] - inp_bed['stop']
    inp_bed['next_region_overlap'] = inp_bed['next_start'] < inp_bed['stop']
    intermediate_bed = inp_bed
    return intermediate_bed
```

And this gives me output like this:

```
print bed_prepare(bed)
```

> ```
>        chr     start      stop geneID  next_start  distance_to_next  next_region_overlap
> 0    chr13  32889584  32889814  BRCA2    32890536               722  False
> 1    chr13  32890536  32890737  BRCA2    32893194              2457  False
> 2    chr13  32893194  32893307  BRCA2    32893282               -25  True
> 3    chr13  32893282  32893400  BRCA2    32893363               -37  True
> 4    chr13  32893363  32893466  BRCA2    32899127              5661  False
> ```

I want to put this intermediate dataframe into the following function in order get the desired output (shown below):

```
new_bed = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0,len(columns))),columns=columns)

def bed_collapse(intermediate_bed, new_bed,columns=columns):
    for row in bed.itertuples():
    output = {}
        if row[7] == False:
            # If row doesn't overlap next row, insert into new dataframe unchanged.                                   
            output_row = list(row[1:5])
        if row[7] == True:
            # For overlapping rows take the chromosome and start coordinate                                           
            output_row = list(row[1:3])
            # Iterate to next row                                                                                     
            bed.itertuples().next()
            # Append stop coordinate and geneID                                                                       
            output_row.append(row[3])
        output_row.append(row[4])
        #print output_row                                                                                             
        for k, v in zip(columns,output_row): otpt[k] = v
        #print output                                                                                                 
        new_bed = new_bed.append(otpt,ignore_index=True)
    output_bed = new_bed
    return output_bed


int_bed = bed_prepare(bed)
print bed_collapse(int_bed,new_bed)
```

Desired output:

> ```
>   chr     start       stop        geneID
> 0 chr13   32889584    32889814    BRCA2
> 1 chr13   32890536    32890737    BRCA2
> 2 chr13   32893194    32893466    BRCA2
> 5 chr13   32899127    32899242    BRCA2
> ```

However, when I run the function I get my original dataframe back unchanged. I know that the problem is when I try to call bed.itertuples().next(), as this is clearly not quite the right syntax/location for the call. But I don't know the correct way to rectify this.

Some pointers would be great.

SB :)

### Update

This is a [BED file](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1) where each row refers to an amplicon (genomic region) with start and stop coordinates. Some of the amplicons overlap; ie the start coordinate is before the stop coordinate on the previous row. Therefore I need to identify which rows overlap and concatenate the correct starts and stops so that each row represents and entirely unique amplicon which doesn't overlap any other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the bed_prepare function to check for overlaps in previous and next genomic regions:

```
def bed_prepare(inp_bed):
    ''' Takes pandas dataframe bed file and identifies which regions overlap '''
    inp_bed['next_start'] = inp_bed['start'].shift(periods=-1)
    inp_bed['distance_to_next'] = inp_bed['next_start'] - inp_bed['stop']
    inp_bed['next_region_overlap'] = inp_bed['next_start'] <= inp_bed['stop']
    inp_bed['previous_stop'] = inp_bed['stop'].shift(periods=1)
    inp_bed['distance_from_previous'] = inp_bed['start'] - inp_bed['previous_stop']
    inp_bed['previous_region_overlap'] = inp_bed['previous_stop'] >= inp_bed['start']
    intermediate_bed = inp_bed
    return intermediate_bed
```

And then I used the Boolean outputs from these to do the variable storing for the writing step:

```
# Create empty dataframe to fill with parsed values                                                                   
new_bed = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0,len(columns))),columns=columns,dtype=int)

def bed_collapse(intermediate_bed, new_bed,columns=columns):
    ''' Takes a pandas dataframe bed file with overlap information and returns                                        
    genomic regions without overlaps '''
    output_row = []
    for row in bed.itertuples():
        output = {}
        if row[7] == False and row[10] == False:
            # If row doesn't overlap next row, insert into new dataframe unchanged.                                   
            output_row = list(row[1:5])
        elif row[7] == True and row[10] == False:
            # Only next region overlaps; take the chromosome and start coordinate                                     
            output_row = list(row[1:3])
        elif row[7] == True and row[10] == True:
            # Next and previous regions overlap. Skip row.                                                            
            pass
        elif row[7] == False and row[10]  == True:
            # Only previous region overlaps; append stop coordinate and geneID to output_row variable                 
            output_row.append(row[3])
            output_row.append(row[4])
        if row[7] == False:
            #Zip columns and output_row values together to form a dict for appending                                  
            for k, v in zip(columns,output_row): output[k] = v
            #print output                                                                                             
            new_bed = new_bed.append(output,ignore_index=True)
    output_bed = new_bed
    return output_bed
```

This has now solved my problem and gives the desired output specified in the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you some pointers.

One pointer is that you want the get the rows based on a Series consisting of booleans that is shifted. Probably you can get a new shifted Series using:

```
Boolean_Series = intermediate_bed.loc[:,'next_region_overlap'].shift(periods=1, freq=None, axis=0, **kwds)
```

More background about this function: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Second pointer is that by using this shifted Series you can get your Dataframe by:

```
int_bed = bed.loc[Boolean_Series, :]
```

More about indexing can be found here: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html

These are only pointers now, I do not know if this an actual working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand why you are doing what you are doing, but you can get your desired output by simply using indexing.  e.g.

```
# assume your data is stored in <df>
# call the temporary dataframe <tmp>
tmp = df[ ['chr','start','stop','geneID'] ][(df.stop - df.start.shift(-1))>0]
```

Is that what you are trying to do, ultimately?

UPDATE
Ok, I see what you are doing.  Bear in mind that I have never worked with any genome data, so I have no idea how many rows are in your columns so simple "looping" may be quite slow (if you have a few billion rows this could take a while), but it is the only solution that comes to mind.  Here is the first thing to come to mind (NOTE: this is not a finished product since you need to determine how to handle the NaN's that are introduced and how to handle the loop termination).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index = [0,1,2,3,4,5],columns=['chr','start','stop','geneID'])

df['chr']    = np.array( ['chr13']*6 )
df['start']  = np.array( [32889584,32890536,32893194,32893282,32893363,32899127] )
df['stop']   = np.array( [32889814,32890737,32893307,32893400,32893466,32899242] )
df['geneID'] = np.array( ['BRCA2']*6 )

# calculate difference between start/stop times for adjacent rows
# this will effectively "look into the future" to see if the upcoming row has 
# a start time that is greater than the current stop time
df['tdiff'] = (df.start - df.stop.shift(1)).shift(-1)

# create new dataframe
df_cut = df.copy()*0

r = 0
while r < df.shape[0]:
    if df.tdiff[r] > 0:
        df_cut.iloc[r] = df.iloc[r]
        r+=1

    elif df.tdiff.iloc[r] < 0: # have to determine how you will handle the NaN's later
        df_cut.chr.iloc[r] = df.chr.iloc[r]
        df_cut.start.iloc[r] = df.start.iloc[r]
        df_cut.geneID.iloc[r] = df.geneID.iloc[r]

        # get the next-valid row and put "stop" value into <df_cut>
        df_cut.stop.iloc[r] = df.ix[r:][df.tdiff>0].stop.iloc[0]

        # determine new index location for <r>
        r = df.ix[r:][df.tdiff>0].index[0] + 1

# eliminate empty rows
df_cut = df_cut[df_cut.start<>0]
```

After running:

```
>>> df_cut
     chr     start      stop geneID  tdiff
0  chr13  32889584  32889814  BRCA2    722
1  chr13  32890536  32890737  BRCA2   2457
2  chr13  32893194  32893466  BRCA2     -0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's not quite what I'm after. The new dataframe your code gives me is the same as my intermediate one. I've updated the original post to increase the clarity. Hopefully that'll help. :)

Answer (score 1):

[pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) will allow you to do this super-quickly in one line of code:

```
import pyranges as pr

c = """Chromosome     Start       End        geneID
chr13   32889584    32889814    BRCA2
chr13   32890536    32890737    BRCA2
chr13   32893194    32893307    BRCA2
chr13   32893282    32893400    BRCA2
chr13   32893363    32893466    BRCA2
chr13   32899127    32899242    BRCA2"""

gr = pr.from_string(c)
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | geneID     |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
# | chr13        |  32889584 |  32889814 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32890536 |  32890737 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32893194 |  32893307 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32893282 |  32893400 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32893363 |  32893466 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32899127 |  32899242 | BRCA2      |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 6 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.

m = gr.merge(by="geneID")
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# | Chromosome   |     Start |       End | geneID     |
# | (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
# |--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
# | chr13        |  32889584 |  32889814 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32890536 |  32890737 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32893194 |  32893466 | BRCA2      |
# | chr13        |  32899127 |  32899242 | BRCA2      |
# +--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
# Unstranded PyRanges object has 4 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
# For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

Note that `by="geneID"` makes it so intervals are only merged if they overlap and have the same value for `geneID`. See also the method cluster if you want to merge the interval meta-data with a custom function.