# Finding the closest date given a date in a groupby dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to generate the `Last_Payment_Date` field in my pandas dataframe, and would need to find the closest `Payment_Date` before the given `Order_Date` for each customer (i.e. groupby).

`Payment_Date` will always occur after `Order_Date`, but may take different periods of time, which is difficult to use sorting and shift to find the nearest date.

[Masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409335/comparing-pandas-dataframe-rows-dropping-rows-with-overlapping-dates) seems like a possible way but I've not been able to figure a way on how to use it.

Appreciate all the help I could get!

```
Cust_No  Order_Date  Payment_Date  Last_Payment_Date
      A    5/8/2014      6/8/2014                Nat
      B    6/8/2014      1/5/2015                Nat
      B    7/8/2014      7/8/2014                Nat
      A    8/8/2014      1/5/2015           6/8/2014
      A    9/8/2014     10/8/2014           6/8/2014
      A  10/11/2014    12/11/2014          10/8/2014
      B  11/12/2014      1/1/2015           7/8/2014
      B    1/2/2015      2/2/2015           1/1/2015
      A    2/5/2015      5/5/2015           1/5/2015
      B    3/5/2015      4/5/2015           2/2/2015
```

Comment: Will ```Payment_Date``` always come before the next ```Order_Date```?

Comment: No, as reflected in the first two records of Cust B. In the case where no previous Payment_Date could be found, Nat should be reflected. Thanks!

Comment: In trying to answer answer my own questions, can you double check that the column you've provided for ```Last_Payment_Date``` is 100% correct? Some of the dates don't match (2/5/2015 vs 2/2/2015) and I want to make sure I will get you exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm very sorry about the typo! I've corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Series.searchsorted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) largely does what you want -- it
can be used to find where the `Order_Date`s fit inside `Payment_Date`s. In
particular, it returns the ordinal indices corresponding to where each
`Order_Date` would need to be inserted in order to keep the `Payment_Dates`
sorted. For example, suppose

```
In [266]: df['Payment_Date']
Out[266]: 
0   2014-06-08
2   2014-07-08
4   2014-10-08
5   2014-12-11
6   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-05
3   2015-01-05
7   2015-02-02
9   2015-04-05
8   2015-05-05
Name: Payment_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [267]: df['Order_Date']
Out[267]: 
0   2014-05-08
2   2014-07-08
4   2014-09-08
5   2014-10-11
6   2014-11-12
1   2014-06-08
3   2014-08-08
7   2015-01-02
9   2015-03-05
8   2015-02-05
Name: Order_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

then `searchsorted` returns

```
In [268]: df['Payment_Date'].searchsorted(df['Order_Date'])
Out[268]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 5, 8, 8])
```

The first value, 0, for example, indicates that the `Order_Date`, `2014-05-08`,
would have to be inserted at ordinal index 0 (before the `Payment_Date`
`2014-06-08`) to keep the `Payment_Date`s in sorted order. The second value, 1,
indicates that the `Order_Date`, `2014-07-08`, would have to be inserted at
ordinal index 1 (after the `Payment_Date` `2014-06-08` and before `2014-07-08`)
to keep the `Payment_Date`s in sorted order. And so on for the other indices.

Now, of course, there are some complications:

1. The `Payment_Dates` need to be in sorted order for `searchsorted` to return a
   meaningful result:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values(by=['Payment_Date'])
   ```
2. We need to group by the `Cust_No`

   ```
   grouped = df.groupby('Cust_No')
   ```
3. We want the index of the `Payment_Date` which comes *before* the
   `Order_Date`. Thus, we really need the decrease the index by one:

   ```
   idx = grp['Payment_Date'].searchsorted(grp['Order_Date']) 
   result = grp['Payment_Date'].iloc[idx-1]
   ```

So that `grp['Payment_Date'].iloc[idx-1]` would grab the the *prior* `Payment_Date`.

4. When `searchsorted` returns 0, the `Order_Date` is less than all
   `Payment_Date`s. We want a NaT in this case.

   ```
   result[idx == 0] = pd.NaT
   ```

---

So putting it all togther,

```
import pandas as pd
NaT = pd.NaT
T = pd.Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cust_No': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'expected': [
        NaT,  NaT,  NaT, T('2014-06-08'), T('2014-06-08'), T('2014-10-08'), 
        T('2014-07-08'), T('2015-01-01'), T('2015-01-05'), T('2015-02-02')], 
    'Order_Date': [
        T('2014-05-08'), T('2014-06-08'), T('2014-07-08'), T('2014-08-08'), 
        T('2014-09-08'), T('2014-10-11'), T('2014-11-12'), T('2015-01-02'), 
        T('2015-02-05'), T('2015-03-05')], 
    'Payment_Date': [
        T('2014-06-08'), T('2015-01-05'), T('2014-07-08'), T('2015-01-05'), 
        T('2014-10-08'), T('2014-12-11'), T('2015-01-01'), T('2015-02-02'), 
        T('2015-05-05'), T('2015-04-05')]})

def last_payment_date(s, df):
    grp = df.loc[s.index]
    idx = grp['Payment_Date'].searchsorted(grp['Order_Date']) 
    result = grp['Payment_Date'].iloc[idx-1]
    result[idx == 0] = pd.NaT
    return result

df = df.sort_values(by=['Payment_Date'])    
grouped = df.groupby('Cust_No')
df['Last_Payment_Date'] = grouped['Payment_Date'].transform(last_payment_date, df)

print(df)
```

yields

```
  Cust_No Order_Date Payment_Date   expected Last_Payment_Date
0       A 2014-05-08   2014-06-08        NaT               NaT
2       B 2014-07-08   2014-07-08        NaT               NaT
4       A 2014-09-08   2014-10-08 2014-06-08        2014-06-08
5       A 2014-10-11   2014-12-11 2014-10-08        2014-10-08
6       B 2014-11-12   2015-01-01 2014-07-08        2014-07-08
1       B 2014-06-08   2015-01-05        NaT               NaT
3       A 2014-08-08   2015-01-05 2014-06-08        2014-06-08
7       B 2015-01-02   2015-02-02 2015-01-01        2015-01-01
9       B 2015-03-05   2015-04-05 2015-02-02        2015-02-02
8       A 2015-02-05   2015-05-05 2015-01-05        2015-01-05
```